# How do i send a message in a specific channel in discord using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've tried to use

```js
<client>.channels.cache.get('1234567890').send('Hello world.');
```

and

```js
<guild>.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'general').send('Hello world.');
```

but neither has worked. This is the code that I have:

```js
module.exports = {
    commands: 'strike',
    minArgs: 2,
    expectedArgs: "<Target user's @> <Role>",
    permissions: 'MANAGE_ROLES',
    callback: (message, args, client) => {
        const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (!targetUser) {
            message.reply('Please specify someone to strike.')
            return
        }

        args.shift()

        const roleName = args.join(' ')
        const { guild } = message

        const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
            return role.name === roleName
        })
        if (!role) {
            message.reply(`There is no role with the name "${roleName}"`)
            return
        }

        const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUser.id)
        member.roles.add(role)

        client.channels.cache.get('870165929282138153').send(`<@${member.user.id}> has been striked.`)
    },
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried it using `.fetch()`? Example: `client.channels.fetch('870165929282138153')
  .then(channel => channel.send('<@${member.user.id}> has been striked'))`

Comment: Or you add an `await` to the beginning of the line. But you have to make your `callback` function **async** in order to get this running

Comment: **Or** try it using `message.guild.channels [...]`

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to a specific channel using its id, you can use :

```
message.guild.channels.cache.get(ID).send(MESSAGE);
```

The `channels` collection come from the `guild` object, and `.cache.get()` returns a channel object.

You can learn more about it here : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels

Answer (score -1):

Finding channel by the name:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.name === "channelName")
channel.send(message)
```

Finding channel by the Id:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.id === "ID")
channel.send(message)
```

Comment: `Collection#get` only accepts an ID/snowflake, not a function.